# Using Qt tools extension with visual studio 2019 and I get so many errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt6, qt-vs-addin

I downloaded Qt6.1.2, I installed the Qt tools extension in visual studio 2019 and I added the version its path. Whenever I start a new Qt widgets application project I get a lot of errors like this one:

**abc Error (active)    E2783   expected a comma (the one-argument version of static_assert is not enabled in this mode)    Project_Name    C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qanystringview.h**
or this one

**abc Error (active)    E0325   inline specifier allowed on function declarations only  Project_Name    C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qrgb.h**

And for the records the Qt creator works just fine but I need to write code on visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and going to the solution explorer and right clicking properties->General, and changing the C++ Language Standard to C++ 17 (it was C++ 14) fixed the errors.

I learned this from the YouTube video posted by Alex Toma:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heiyPLJLBS8

So the credit goes to Alex - thanks!